# How can i make optional Date of birth and Gender field in PHP

Tags: php

Here is the code, I would like to make below two fields optional, I don't have much knowledge in PHP, I have tried by hiding both sections by (display: none) and tried to remove both sections but when I trying to removing sections it's showing blank page.

This is for Birthday

```
            <div class="global-input-wrapp days" id="bdy">
          <select name="birth_day" id="subscription_day">
                  <option value=""><?php echo $page_Lang['day'][$DefaultLang];?></option>
                    <?php
                       $strDay='';
                       for ($i=1; $i<=31; $i++) {
                          $strDay=(string)$i;
                          if($i<10) $strDay='0'.$strDay;
                   ?> 
                   <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                       <?php echo $strDay; ?>
                   </option>
                   <?php } ?>
                </select>
          <select name="birth_month" id="subscription_month">
                    <option value=""><?php echo $page_Lang['month'][$DefaultLang];?></option>
                    <?php
                        $months = array(1 => $page_Lang['jan'][$DefaultLang], 2 => $page_Lang['feb'][$DefaultLang], 3 => $page_Lang['mar'][$DefaultLang], 4 => $page_Lang['apr'][$DefaultLang], 5 => $page_Lang['may'][$DefaultLang], 6 => $page_Lang['jun'][$DefaultLang], 7 => $page_Lang['jul'][$DefaultLang], 8 => $page_Lang['aug'][$DefaultLang], 9 => $page_Lang['sep'][$DefaultLang], 10 =>$page_Lang['oct'][$DefaultLang], 11 => $page_Lang['nov'][$DefaultLang], 12 => $page_Lang['dec'][$DefaultLang]);
                        $transposed = array_slice($months, date('n'), 12, true) + array_slice($months, 0, date('n'), true);
                        $last8 = array_reverse(array_slice($transposed, -8, 12, true), true); 
                      foreach ($months as $num => $name) {
                    ?> <option value="<?php echo $num; ?>">
                    <?php echo $name; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                 </select>
               <select name="birth_year" id="subscription_year">
                   <option value=""><?php echo $page_Lang['year'][$DefaultLang];?></option>
                   <?php  for ($i=1950; $i<date('Y'); $i++) { ?>
                   <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                   <?php echo $i; ?>
                    </option>
                   <?php } ?>
                </select>
        </div>
```

This is the code for Gender

```
<div class="global-input-wrapp" id="gender">
          <div class="i_bg">
            <input type="radio" class="with-gap" name="gender" id="man" value="male">
            <label for="man"><?php echo $page_Lang['male'][$DefaultLang];?></label>
          </div>
          <div class="i_bg">
            <input type="radio" class="with-gap" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
            <label for="female"><?php echo $page_Lang['female'][$DefaultLang];?></label>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: one option would be to add hidden fields for both `birth_day` and `gender` (before the real form elements)  with a default option that you know can be ignored serverside.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to make these fields optional

Comment: In what sense optional? They are currently optional as there is no `required` attribute so the user can simply NOT complete these fields. Please clarify what you mean by `optional`

Comment: Share the whole form fields also please do share you validation conditions.